# server-side mvc3 validation for form not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a form in my View. The fields on the form are derived from the Model. 
I have just given a single variable to shorten the code here.

```
MODEL:
public class abc
{
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

VIEW:
<body onload="SetButton()">
@using (Html.BeginForm("myaction","mycontroller",FormMethod.POST, new {id="myform"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.name)
}
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetButton{
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML='<input type="submit" value="Next"             style="width:90px" onclick="myform.submit()"/>';
}
</script>

Layout Page:
<div id="button"></div>
```

On clicking the 'Next' button, validation does not occur. The form gets submitted even if there is nothing entered for 'name' field.If the button is put inside the Form(myform), validation works.Why isn't the validation working for the code shown?

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button is outside of the form. This is not possible. A submit button must be placed inside the corresponding `<form>` element. So you will need to move the `<div id="button"></div>` inside the form.

If for some reason the div needs to stay outside the form (which is semantically incorrect) you need to use javascript and in this case you could use a normal button and not a submit button.

Another important aspect of html forms is that they **cannot** be nested. So if you have another form in your layout you cannot have a nested form inside your view. That's invalid HTML and results in unexpected behavior.

As far as the server side validation is concerned, make sure that the controller action you are posting your form to takes your view model as action argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(abc model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't have any nested forms. Actually, the button(s) are part of the Footer,which is common to multiple screens, so I decided to keep it outside the Form inside the Layout page. Changing the "submit" type to "button" didn't work.Is there a way to keep the buttons outside and do the validation?

Comment: @karank, yes, it is possible. You should use a button type instead of a submit type and then have your controller action take the view model as action argument. Then if the view model is decorated with the proper validation attributes, error messages will automatically be added to the ModelState.